# Подключение к USB устройству (JS)

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток!

Потратил n-е количество времени, пытаясь получить доступ к USB устройству с Web страницы, используя WebUSB API, но так ничего и не вышло.

Хочется узнать, можно ли вообще получить доступ к устройству и получать с него данные? Пытался получить доступ к сканеру штрих кодов POS Sector BC-002.

Заранее спасибо за любые ответы!

Comment: Браузер последний хром и страница отдаётся по https?

Comment: @AlexeyTen последний, пробую на https странице через dev-tools.

Comment: Пользовался гайдом от Google: [Ссылка](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web), но ничего не выходит...